# Guardar resultado de una petición GET con dos parámetros

Tags: javascript, ajax

Necesito almacenar la respuesta de una petición `GET` con dos parámetros en `JavaScript`. Tengo el siguiente código y no obtengo la respuesta adecuada.

Aquí relleno el campo `select` del formulario con todos los destinos que tengo en mi base de datos:

```
function Solicita_Datos () {    
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/destination";
    peticion.onreadystatechange = tratarDestinoForm;
    peticion.open("GET", url, true);
    peticion.send();    
}

function tratarDestinoForm () {
    //Se encarga de tratar las respuestas que vienen del servidor
    var respuestaForm;
    if (peticion.readyState == 4) {
        if (peticion.status == 200) {
            respuesta = JSON.parse(peticion.responseText);
            RellenaSelect(respuesta);
        } else
            alert("Ocurrio un problema con la URL.");
    }
}


function RellenaSelect (los_datos) {
    var otro_select = document.getElementById('destinoForm');
    for (i = 0; i < los_datos.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = los_datos[i].provincia;
        opt.innerHTML = los_datos[i].provincia;
        otro_select.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

En esta función guardo los valores del destino y del peso introducidos en un formulario:

```
function calcular () {
    var peso = document.getElementById('peso').value;
    var destino = document.getElementById('destinoForm').selectedIndex;
    var destino = destino + 1;
    obtenerTransporte(destino, peso);
}
```

En esta función hago la petición `AJAX`:

```
function obtenerTransporte (destino, peso) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/providerD/" + destino + "/" + peso;
    peticion.onreadystatechange = respuestaTransporte();
    peticion.open("GET", url, true);
    peticion.send(destino, peso);
}

function respuestaTransporte() {
    var respuesta;
    texto = "<tr></th><th>Nombre</th><th>Importe</th><th>Entrega</th><th>Peso</th></tr>";
    if (peticion.readyState == 4)

        if (peticion.status == 200) {

            respuesta = peticion.responseText;
            var cadena = respuesta.split("<");
            var respuestaV = cadena[0];
            var dato = JSON.parse(respuestaV);

            for (var i = 0; i < dato.length; i++) {    
                texto += "<tr><td>" + dato[i].nombre + "</td><td>" + dato[i].importe + "</td><td>" +
                dato[i].entrega + "</td><td>" + dato[i].peso + "</td><td>" + "</td>";    
            } 

            document.getElementById('tabla').innerHTML = texto;
        }
    else alert("Ocurrio un problema con la URL");
}
```

El problema que tengo es que según como está codificado, la petición que estoy guardando en la variable dato es la petición que devuelve todos los destinos, no la que tiene dos parámetros. ¿Por qué puede estar pasando esto? ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: 1. No definas `peticion` como global, si no como variable local. Cada función que hace una llamada al API debe tener su propio objeto `XMLHttpRequest`. 2. Estás ejecutando la función 
 `obtenerTransporte` en lugar de asignarla al `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: @gugadev perdona pero no entiendo muy bien lo que dices, ya que he declarado una variable peticion dentro de la función `obtener transporte` y tampoco funciona. Podrías poner el código al que te refieres? Tampoco entiendo lo de que no estoy asignando  `obtener transporte` al `onreadystatechange`, ¿cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: @gugadev puedes explicar con mas detalle lo que comentabas?

Comment: @Lara, estas usando la variable `petición` en `Solicita_Datos` y en `obtenerTransporte`., esta variable debería ser una por cada petición, no una común para las dos peticiones `Ajax`. Por otro lado, en esta línea `peticion.onreadystatechange = respuestaTransporte();` estás ejecutando la función `respuestaTransporte` y el resultado de la misma lo estás asignando al `onreadystatechange`, fíjate como lo tienes echo en `Solicita_Datos` y haz lo mismo. Esto es lo que te han querido decir anteriomente.

Comment: Conseguí solucionarlo! Gracias, efectivamente es por lo que decíais.

Comment: @Lara, me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado. Un saludo ;)